# Cannot implicity convert type void to string c#

Tags: c#

I am getting this fault message. I am trying to do something but it's totally wrong i guess. anyway please check the codes i wrote it below. the codes are in dutch but if it's not possible to understand for you guys, i'll translate it to english.

cheers,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pc pc = new Pc();
        PcShop pcShop = new PcShop();
        Console.WriteLine(pc.GeefOmschrijving());



        string result = pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc); //here i am getting the fault message.

        switch (result)
        { 
            case "1":
                pcShop.PCToevoegen(new Pc("DF6", "i7", 16, 500));
                pcShop.PCToevoegen(new Pc("ZER6D23", "i7", 8, 1000));
                pcShop.PCToevoegen(new Pc("6SDS", "i7", 32, 2000));

                    break;
        }

                Console.ReadLine();


class Pc
    {
        private string code;
        private int geheugen;
        private int hardeschrijf;
        private string processor;

        public string Processor
        {
            get { return processor; }
            set { processor = value; }
        }

        public int Hardeschrijf
        {
            get { return hardeschrijf; }
            set { hardeschrijf = value; }
        }

        public int Geheugen
        {
            get { return geheugen; }
            set { geheugen = value; }
        }

        public string Code
        {
            get { return code; }
            set { code = value; }
        }

        public Pc()
        {
            processor = "";
            code = "";
            geheugen = 0;
            hardeschrijf = 0; 


        }

        public Pc(string code, string processor, int geheugen, int hardeschrijf)
        {
            this.code = code;
            this.geheugen = geheugen;
            this.processor = processor;
            this.hardeschrijf = hardeschrijf;
        }

        public string GeefOmschrijving()
        {
            string omschrijving = "Welkom in de PC shop.Kies een van de volgende opties:" + Environment.NewLine;
            omschrijving += "1. Overzicht winkel " + Environment.NewLine;
            omschrijving += "2. Overzicht - geheugen selectie <Gb> " + Environment.NewLine;
            omschrijving +="3. Overzicht - processor type selectie "+ Environment.NewLine;
            omschrijving += "4. Overzicht - harde schrijf selectie <Gb>"+Environment.NewLine;
            omschrijving +="9. Stoppen ";
            return omschrijving;
        }

 class PcShop
    {
        Pc pc = new Pc();
        private string pcVoorad;

        public string PcVoorad
        {
            get { return pcVoorad; }
            set {

                pcVoorad = value; }
        }

        public void PCToevoegen(Pc pc)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Code: "+ pc.Code +" CPU "+ pc.Processor + " Geheugen " + pc.Geheugen+ " Harddisk: "+ pc.Geheugen);
        return;


    }
```

Comment: You have this multiple typo `hardeschrijf`, I suspect you meant `hardeschijf`, but you should really try to use English words, because it will help you and people that want to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line isn't going to work

```
string result = pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc); //here i am getting the fault message.
```

because `PCToevoegen` has a `void` return type (i.e. it doesn't return anything). You need to either update this method to return the `string` you output to the console i.e.

```
public string PCToevoegen(Pc pc)
{
    return String.Format("Code: "+ pc.Code +" CPU "+ pc.Processor + " Geheugen " + pc.Geheugen+ " Harddisk: "+ pc.Geheugen);
}
```

Or just call the method and expect nothing to return i.e.

```
pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc);
```

Comment: yeah i see what i did there. but now when i start debugging, i see the  list of computers without pressing 1.

Comment: @ciguli14 seems to me your `string result = ...` code should really be along the lines of `Console.Write("Enter option: "); string result = Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: yes sir. thanks :) can i ask you one more question? for example if i wanted to show a list with only the code and memory? what i need to do then? i was thinking writing a method in the pcShop class.but how exactly

Comment: @ciguli14 If you want my advice, don't do any console outputs in your models (`pcShop` class), instead add some helper classes to your console app e.g. `PrintPc` - prints all the PC info, `PrintPcSummary` - prints on the code/memory.

Comment: yeah i'll keep it in my mind. but its a school assingment. so it has to be in the model.

Comment: @ciguli14 ok, well in that case you could override the `ToString` method of your `Pc` class and have that output the `Code`/`Memory` properties, or alternatively just add another method to your `pcShop` class.

Comment: :) sorry i have one more. for example: if the user wants to see the harddisc section but only computers with 500 gb harddiscs or whatever.how can we do that? this is my last questio by the way

Answer (score 2):

It helps to let us know what line number the issue is on...

Anyway the method `PCToevoegen` returns `void` but you are trying to assign this to a `string`:

```
string result = pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc);
```

What you are trying to model? If you want to output the PC characteristics as a string then implement this in a `ToString` method in the `PC` class. You can add PCs to the shop based on some other logic and not confuse this with the method to output a textual representation of a PC.

Comment: i also tried like that int result = pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc);

Comment: `void` wouldn't return anything, neither an `int`, nor a `string`

Answer (score 1):

The method

```
 public void PCToevoegen(Pc pc)
```

doesn't return anything (void) but your code tries to get a string as result

```
 string result = pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc);
```

this causes the error.

If you want to return something from the above method you should change its signature and return a string otherwise you shouldn't try to assign a variable (of any kind) to the supposed return value of the method

**Option 1** Change signature and return a string

```
public string PCToevoegen(Pc pc)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Code: "+ pc.Code +" CPU "+ pc.Processor + " Geheugen " + pc.Geheugen+ " Harddisk: "+ pc.Geheugen);
    return "1";
}
```

**Option 2**  Do not try to assign the return value of a void method

```
pcShop.PCToevoegen(pc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You return `void` (nothing) from `PCToevoegen` but then you are trying to work with `PCToevoegen` return value.